# Prove there exists a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a measurable real-valued function on an interval
$[a,b]$. Prove that given $\delta>0$ there is a continuous
function $\phi$ on $[a,b]$ such that $m(\{x: f(x) \ne g(x)\}) < \delta$.
Is the same true for a function $f$ defined on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Hint: Use Lusin's theorem and the Tietze extension theorem for the first part. For the second one note that $\delta = \sum_{n \ge 1} \delta 2^{-n}$ and decompose $\mathbb R$ into intervals

Comment: I've added TeX to your question (math rendering). You should check where you want to write $f$, $g$ and $\phi$, the question seems to be mixed-up a little.

Comment: Martini, can you please provide a decomposition of R into the intervals you are talking about? I got the first part down by heart. But I'm still very confused by the second. Thank you!